# jQuery show/hide div if button group pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first function shows the `.check` div if any of the inputs that have `data-target="check"` are checked.

Now I am trying to simulate the same `checked / unchecked` states of the checkboxes and have the function work the same way but for `buttons` that are `clicked` and then `un-clicked` by pressing the `#clear` button.

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var source = $(this);
  var target = $('.' + source.attr('data-target'));
  if ($('input[data-target=' + source.attr('data-target') + ']:checked').length) target.show();
  else target.hide();
});
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var clear = $("#clear");
  if ($(this) !== clear) {
    var source = $(this);
    var target = $('.' + source.attr('data-target'));
    if ($('button[data-target=' + source.attr('data-target') + ']').length) target.show();
  } else {
    if ($(this) === clear) {
      target.hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="name" data-target="check" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="name" data-target="check" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="name" data-target="check" value="3">
<button data-target="button" value="4"></button>
<button data-target="button" value="5"></button>
<button id="clear">clear</button>

<div class="check">check</div>
<div class="button">button</div>
```

Comment: are you looking for toggle button kind of i.e  on first click checked and on clear button un check ?

Comment: If a button is clicked then show the div. If clear is then pressed, hide it

Comment: could you elaborate on what is not working or what problems you do encounter?

Comment: Clicking #clear doesn't hide the buttons div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a couple of things that are keeping this from working.  One is how you're comparing objects - now how I used `!$(this).is(clear)`, and the other is that you keep redefining target inside the `$('button').on`... function.  Here is how it should look, I changed the variable name for clarity:

```
var button_target;
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var source = $(this);
  var target = $('.' + source.attr('data-target'));
  if ($('input[data-target=' + source.attr('data-target') + ']:checked').length) target.show();
  else target.hide();
});
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var clear = $("#clear");
  if (!$(this).is(clear)) {
    var source = $(this);
    button_target = $('.' + source.attr('data-target'));
    if ($('button[data-target=' + source.attr('data-target') + ']').length) button_target.show();
  } else {
    if ($(this).is(clear)) {
      button_target.hide();
    }
  }
});
```